# Android app http post request got libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, http, permissions

I am in trouble with http post request in my android app:

```
libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

My app works well on most of the Android device except one android phone, my app can not connect to the internet by http on that phone. 
But other apps can run well on that android phone, such as browser.

I found there was some queston about `EACCES (Permission denied)`, and I checked the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission in my App, there is no problem about it.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:573)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:693)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:837)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:77)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:188)
at cn.com.fetion.android.common.ability.HttpProxy.openDataOutputStream(HttpProxy.java:252)
at cn.com.fetion.javacore.v11.network.HttpConnectionThread.doSendMessage(HttpConnectionThread.java:188)
at cn.com.fetion.javacore.v11.network.HttpConnectionThread.doSendMessage(HttpConnectionThread.java:262)
at cn.com.fetion.javacore.v11.network.HttpConnectionThread.doSendMessage(HttpConnectionThread.java:262)
at cn.com.fetion.javacore.v11.network.HttpConnectionThread.doSendMessage(HttpConnectionThread.java:262)
at cn.com.fetion.javacore.v11.network.ConnectionThread.executeConnectionRequest(ConnectionThread.java:185)
at cn.com.fetion.javacore.v11.network.ConnectionThread.run(ConnectionThread.java:137)
at cn.com.fetion.javacore.v11.network.HttpConnectionThread.run(HttpConnectionThread.java:1)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:558)
```

Comment: Here is the permission in manifest file :<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: please the whole manifest - sometimes the problem is the placement of this line